# How to send data params from Java Code to HTML?

Tags: java, html, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have written a HTML for login and registration for existing website.I can successfully do login and registration using httpclient in java code.
When ever user tries to login then my java code will hit the old website using httpclient and gets the response. 
Now I have some fields in that response, which are required for my next ajax call params.Now I need that params in my form.

**How to Send those required params from java code to my html form?**

Thanks in Advance for all your Suggestions and Answers.

Comment: What technology are you using for your server ? Servlets ? Spring ? Can you add the code of the server part ?

Comment: @reos Thanks actually i'm practising the ajax calls for different sites. I used httpclient apache and the core java for hit my requested url. My target is to get the dropdown values(almost 10k options list) in a website, all the values using Ajax Post call.

Comment: What you want to do is to send from your java client html parameters to X server using HttpClient?

Comment: I can send the params like that, But i'm trying to do a ajax call to the x server to get some dropdown values.

Answer (score 0):

To make a GET call with ajax you need

```
//create the XMLHttpRequest object
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
//add a function to process the response
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        showContacts(response);
    }
}   
/set the URL        
xmlhttp.open("GET", "URL", true);
//invoke send
xmlhttp.send();
```

To make a POST call with ajax you need to do the same as with GET plus.

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "URL", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

//write the params
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
var params = 'name=' + name + '&phone=' + phone + '&address=' + address;
//send
xmlhttp.send(params);
```

You can also use JQuery to make the AJAX call

GET

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "URL",
    success: function( response ){
        showContacts(response);
    }
});
```

POST

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "URL",
    data: {name: $('#name').val(), phone: $('#phone').val(), address: $('#address').val()}, 
    success: function( response ){
        showContacts(response)
    },
    error: function( response ){
        alert(response);
    }
});
```